# Definite integration proof

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, solution-verification

**Question:** Suppose that f is continuous on R. Prove that

$$\int_{a}^{b} f(-x)dx = \int_{-b}^{-a} f(x)dx$$

I'm trying to figure out how to prove the equation above. I've seen a similar work on MSE but the signs are different. Here's my work for this specific case. Feel free to check if all is good.

**My Answer:**

\begin{align}
\int_{a}^{b}f(-x)\,dx
&=\int_{-a}^{-b}f(u)\cdot(-du) &&  u = -x,\quad du = -dx
\\
&=-\int_{-a}^{-b}f(u)\,du
\\
&=\int_{-b}^{-a}f(u)\,du
\\
&=\int_{-b}^{-a}f(x)\,dx && u = x,\quad du = dx
\end{align}

Comment: The limit will change to $(-b,-a)$ in the first step it self.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I've updated the post

Comment: @What you have now is fine.

Comment: Your proof attempt is good now : I would just say the last line doesn't require justification , a statement like $u=x ; du=dx$ is avoidable.